# How to interpret powercfg output and what to do about it

Tags: laptop, powersave

I just now performed this command in the command-line in my Windows 7: `powercfg -energy`

This will analyze the system for 60 seconds and generate an HTML file under your personal folder, detailing errors and warnings. Some errors are kinda stupid, as they merely inform me of how I've set my power settings, others are somewhat difficult to understand and I don't know what to do with them.

For instance:

> The USB device did not enter the
>   Suspend state. Processor power
>   management may be prevented if a USB
>   device does not enter the Suspend
>   state when not in use.

What is this saying about my USB hub and is it something I should worry about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that when your computer enters the Sleep state, that device doesn't sleep, so that it will keep on drawing power. For a laptop this means that battery life is shortened even if you put it into Sleep.

This might be a driver problem, where the driver simply does not implement the Sleep state. It can also be the power management option in the Drive Manager for this device.